# Giving up DI and use BDD and Integration Tests

Tags: scala, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I find it useless and extra work to use dependency injection while you don't follow TDD strictly. When I create an application using DI it leads me to have multiple logical layers (Repositories, Services (Business), Entities, Models, etc). As I don't strictly follow TDD, I find these layers useless and verbose most of the times!

Now using Scala and Play Framework I can use BDD and integration tests more easily than before (I am a C#/.NET developer migrating to Scala/Play).

So is it OK to give up DI and stick with some sort of DDD and use integration tests and BDD instead (which is followed in Play Framework simple tutorials)? Or it's better to learn new methods of DI which introduced in Scala (Cake pattern, MacWire, ...)?

Comment: I don't understand BDD much, nor I follow TDD strictly. But I found that DI is useful to keep the persistence ignorance and keep your BLL separated to UI and DAL, making it portable to other UI / DAL. Moreover, I find it easy to create unit tests at the time I try to debug my application. However, this question seems primarily opinion-based.

Comment: I don't remember the last time I changed the UI / DAL for a specific project. Actually I think that layers have some unavoidable effects on each other which makes them unportable most of the times unless you consider portability from the beginning which has its own costs and you may never use that portability.

Comment: Your application may not live long enough for it need to be ported into other UI/DAL. Today's example, porting your website into mobile-based web is one common example, porting your app to cloud-based service is another one.

Comment: You're right and isn't it a sign that these features are extra for this kind of apps?

Comment: IMHO, it is depend on what kind of apps you designed. If there is not a data access layer (calculator), why would you need it? However as you see that your apps need BDD or DDD, I think it is big enough, or can grod big enough, that sometimes it may need different UI or data access (the data is ported to other webservice, for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TDD `!=` DI `!=` Layered architecture.

BDD `!=` NoTDD.

I suggest you reconsider the purpose and benefits of each of these different, orthogonal practices separately before deciding you need to throw them out all together.

Comment: I think the OP is confusing Dependency Injection the design pattern with a DI framework which requires additional scaffolding

Comment: Ok, and would you please reference me to some practices that help me to decide?